# How to use animate.css shake with less shakes

Tags: html, css, animation, animate.css

I'm using animate.css for a CSS3 shake effect, the CSS looks like the snippet below. Right now it shakes back and forth multiple times and I'd like to cut the shakes in half. Is there a way to do this with animate css3 or do I need to modify the css3 below? If so, what's the best way?

```
@-webkit-keyframes shake {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

@keyframes shake {
  0%, 100% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  }

  10%, 30%, 50%, 70%, 90% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(-10px, 0, 0);
  }

  20%, 40%, 60%, 80% {
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
            transform: translate3d(10px, 0, 0);
  }
}

.shake {
  -webkit-animation-name: shake;
  animation-name: shake;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really sure how you want to "cut the shake in half". Do you mean the speed, sway??

Here is what I came up, [demo](http://codepen.io/rema/pen/nDpBe)

If you want to slow the animation down, change the `-webkit-animation-duration:

Here is a custom cool shake/wobble effect:

```
@keyframes shake {
0% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(2px,1px) rotate(0deg)
}

10% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(-1px,-2px) rotate(-1deg)
}

20% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(-3px,0px) rotate(1deg)
}

30% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(0px,2px) rotate(0deg)
}

40% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(1px,-1px) rotate(1deg)
}

50% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(-1px,2px) rotate(-1deg)
}

60% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(-3px,1px) rotate(0deg)
}

70% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(2px,1px) rotate(-1deg)
}

80% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(-1px,-1px) rotate(1deg)
}

90% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(2px,2px) rotate(0deg)
}

100% {
  -webkit-transform:translate(1px,-2px) rotate(-1deg)
}
}
```

Here is a simple [demo](http://codepen.io/rema/pen/leqJa)

Comment: The current shake goes back and forth ~5 times, I'd like to cut that down to 3... Possible?